# Is .gnupg vital when upgrading 12.04 to 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, gnupg

My "/home/owlsglobal/.gnupg" as not been getting 'backed up' for several months. 
 (No idea why it stopped working.)
  ***Might*** an upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04.1 solve this problem, ***or*** should I solve this problem ***before*** risking an upgrade?  
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "backed up"? Ubuntu doesn't back up your `.gnupg` folder for you. As it is, any keys there aren't used for Ubuntu updates/upgrades.

Comment: Thank you for commenting!
My system uses "Deja Dup Backup Tool" to backup my 'home' folder daily.
I believe the program was bundled with 12.04 when I installed it. 
Under "System Settings" "Backup" is a default program, along with "Details", "Landscape Service", "Time&Date", "Universal Access" and "User Accounts"
Every day for the past two months, I get the warning "/home/owlsglobal/.gnupg" cannot be copied.

Comment: That would make sense, since that folder should only be accessible to you (your user account). I'm guessing the backup service runs under another account.

Comment: Thanks once again.  The only other account is the root.  However,it looks like the really vital answer to my question is in your final sentence: It seems that I can safely upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 without understanding why the 'Deja Dup Backup Tool' is no longer able to copy my gnupg folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upgrade itself from 12.04 to 14.04.1 won't change anything that's in your home folder. However, when you boot into 14.04.1, changes might be made by the programs in that release. Therefore, any folders (or lack thereof) in your home directory won't impact the upgrade.

The most likely reason that your `.gnupg` folder isn't getting backed up by the backup service is because the folder's permissions are `0700`, meaning only you and any programs that run under your user can access that folder. Most likely, the backup service is running under its own user account, and therefore can't read that folder.